# Big Picture Sharepoint Design Question

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am just getting into Sharepoint, and I have a question about having a Sharepoint internet site, and a Sharepoint intranet site.
Is it possible to have an internet site, and have a login type function, that when the user logs in, they are taken to a site like the Team Site? I think I'm trying to integrate an internet/public site with the Sharepoint functions that users are familiar with in an intranet site. 
My goal is to have non-private info on the internet, but once authenticated, the user would be able to upload docs, search docs, see a calendar, that sort of stuff.
Maybe I am not totally clear due to my lack of understanding thus far of Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google keyword here is Forms based authentication.

[Here is a good post to start you off](http://www.devcow.com/blogs/jdattis/archive/2007/02/23/Office-SharePoint-Server-2007-Forms-Based-Authentication-FBA-Walkthrough-Part-1.aspx) and [a second including Mysite setup](http://www.devcow.com/blogs/jdattis/archive/2007/03/01/Office-SharePoint-Server-2007-Forms-Based-Authentication-FBA-w-MySites-Walkthrough-Part-2.aspx)